# double variables are showing as double * and int variables as int * - why?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I'm supposed to write a C program that would print out the minimum integral distance (in kms) from which a pot will break if dropped, and show the number of trials it took to get that number. I'm an absolute beginner in C and I'm unable to understand why I'm getting this error message in Terminal when I enter `gcc ds1.c -o ds1 -lm`:

```
ds1.c:47:86: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
 mum integral distance from which the object breaks when dropped is %f units.", &u);
                                                                    ~^          ~~
ds1.c:48:68: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("The number of trials it took to arrive at this number is %d .", &n);
                                                                   ~^     ~~
                                                                   %ls
```

This is the program that I have written. I'm unable to find out what is wrong here. Please help.

```
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    double u, U, l, m;
    int x, n, i;

    u = pow(2,10);
    printf("Drop the object from %f distance.", U);
    printf("Enter 0 if the object does not break, otherwise, enter 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    n = 1;

    while(x == 0) {
        n = n + 1;
        u = U*n;
        printf("Drop the object from %f distance.", u);
        printf("Enter 0 if the object does not break, otherwise, enter 1: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }

    l = U*(n-1);
    m = (u + l)/2;
    m = floor(m);
    i = 0;

    while(l + 1 < u) {
        i = i + 1;
        printf("Drop the object from %f distance.", m);
        printf("Enter 0 if the object does not break, otherwise, enter 1: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if(x == 0) {
            l = m;
            m = (u + l)/2;
            m = floor(m);
        }
        else {
            u = m;
            m = (u + l)/2;
            m = floor(m);
        }
    }
    n = n + i;
    printf("The minimum integral distance from which the object breaks when dropped is %f units.", &u);
    printf("The number of trials it took to arrive at this number is %d .", &n);


    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: With `printf()`, do not use the `&` operator (unlike with `scanf()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be confusing `printf` and `scanf`. With `printf`, you only need to print the **value** of a variable, so you'd provide it with just the variables `n` and `u`. With `scanf`, it needs to actually read the value into somewhere, so it needs to know the address of the variable (to know where it has to write to), so you provide it with the pointers `&n` and `&u` (remember that `&` gets the address of a variable and is a pointer type). So, the fix is simply to change `printf(..., &u)` to `printf(..., u)` and `printf(..., &n)` to `printf(..., n)`.

Comment: @SuCh Press the green checkbox next to one of the answers to mark your question as solved. Pick the one that helped you the most (or if you're not sure, the one that was posted first).

Comment: `scanf` needs to write the value to somewhere, not “read in the value somewhere”. (It does read it from input, but that is not the issue here).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant to say "read the value into somewhere"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the & from your variables in the printf statements:

```
printf("The minimum integral distance from which the object breaks when dropped is %f units.", u);
printf("The number of trials it took to arrive at this number is %d.", n);
```